# check constraint annotation for allowed values in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have Consumer table in database where I have check constraint on consumer_type column like below:

```
ALTER TABLE consumer
    ADD CONSTRAINT Check_consumer_consumer_type CHECK (consumer_type IN ('ACCOUNT','ORGANIZATION'))
```

Now from hibernate side I want to add  check constraint annotation which will allow only "ACCOUNT" and "ORGANIZATION" value in consumer type table.

Which hibernate / jpa annotation I should use for this purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have the consumer type represented using `String` in your entity you could easily replace it with an enum and Java's type safety would ensure that you will not be able to pass anything else to it.

Using `EnumType.STRING`, the values will be stored as Strings in your database (and mapped back to enum when you load the entity), so no change to your data would be required.

---

#### Example

```
@Entity
public class Consumer {

    public static enum ConsumerType {
        ACCOUNT, ORGANIZATION
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="consumer_type", nullable=false)
    private ConsumerType consumerType;

    // Other properties, getters/setters, ...
}
```